# Не работает last-child

Tags: html, css

Почему не срабатывает `:last-child` ?

```
.group-list .user-name {
border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
.group-list .user-name:last-child {
border-bottom: none;
 }
```

[Полный код](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/96rz47oe/)

```css
.found-item {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6ba;
}
.found-item a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.found-item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8440d;
}
.found-item .user-name {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
.found-item .user-name:hover {
  background: #e6e5e9;
}
.found-item .user-group {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.found-item .icon-group {
  background-position: -13px -1215px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.group-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.group-list .user-name {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
.group-list .user-name:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-list found-item">
  <a href="">
    <div class="user-name">
      <b>Теплов Алексей</b>
      <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
      <div>руководитель группы</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="user-name">
      <b>Теплищев Вадим</b>
      <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
      <div>инженер</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <div class="user-name">
      <b>Теплавина Евгения</b>
      <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
      <div>инженер</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Каждому элементу кроме последнего нужен `border-bottom`. При добавлении `last-child` бордер почему-то удаляется у всех элементов.

**UPD**

В данном случае стили ссылок не влияют на отображение. Им задан свой стиль `text-decoration: none;`

**UPD 1.0**

Всем дивам с классом `.user-name` задан стиль - `border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;`.

**Суть вопроса** - у последнего дива с классом `.user-name` убрать `border-bottom`

PS: Все дивы с классом `.user-name` находятся внутри дива с классом `.group-list`.

**UPD 1.1**

При добавлении стиля `border-bottom` **я использую только дивы с классом `.user-name`** что находится внутри них, не имеет значения (к ним не привязываемся).

Comment: 1) У класса `user-name` убрать тире `username`. 2) Стиль `.grouplist a .username { ... }` 3) Зачем устанавливать border, а потом убирать его?

Comment: Это из-за ссылки (атрибут `href` в теге `<a>`) текст подчёркивается, а не из-за `border-bottom`

Comment: в этом проекте у ссылок нет подчеркивания, им задан `border-bottom` определенного стиля. а в этой части у ссылок вообще нет никакого подчеркивания.

Comment: как именно имя класса может влиять на работу `last-child` ?

Comment: Подчёркивания задаются не через `border`, а через `text-decoration: none;` или если подчёркивания нужны `text-decoration: underline;`

Comment: last-child используется, если внутри тега несколько элементов. Например `<div> <a>1</a> <a>2</a> </div>`, last-child найдёт `<a>2</a>` внутри `<div>`

Comment: `border-bottom` должен применяться ко всем элементам внутри `.username`, кроме `<div>руководитель группы</div>` ?

Comment: у последнего `user-name` должен быть стиль `border-bottom: none;`

Comment: Так его итак там нет, `border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;` не применяется

Comment: Я просто не пойму что толком нужно, убрать подчёркивание у Теплавина Евгения или последние элементы типа `<div>инженер</div>`

Comment: обновила вопрос

Comment: Всё равно не понятно. Border не работает, `#e2e2e2` это серый, а текст подчёркивается цветом ссылки. Я ниже написал ответ, для наглядности и пометил border красным

Comment: в вашем ответе  не используется `last-child`

Comment: Так напиши какой элемент, типа `Теплавина Евгения` или `инженер` и я использую. От скорости ответа зависит  написание кода

Comment: Пожалуйста, `border` применяется сначало на `div` последний, потом убирается через `last-child`. Бордер красный и жирный

Comment: @MarinaVoronova, в такие вопросы стоит вставлять не только отвлеченный css код и ссылку, но и саму разметку, к которой все это применяется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как элемент с классом `user-name` один в контейнере, он подходит под любой селектор (*first-/last-child*), поэтому стоит выбирать те элементы которых в контейнере много, в данном случае это `a` - то есть, границу надо убирать тому элементу с классом `user-name` который лежит в последнем элементе `a`

Селектор примет вид

```
.group-list a:last-child .user-name:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Пример:

```css
.found-item {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b6ba;
}
.found-item a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.found-item a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8440d;
}
.found-item .user-name {
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
.found-item .user-name:hover {
  background: #e6e5e9;
}
.found-item .user-group {
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.found-item .icon-group {
  background-position: -13px -1215px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.group-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.group-list .user-name {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
.group-list a:last-child .user-name:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="group-list found-item">
  <a href="">
    <div class="user-name">
      <b>Теплов Алексей</b>
      <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
      <div>руководитель группы</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="user-name">
      <b>Теплищев Вадим</b>
      <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
      <div>инженер</div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="">
    <div class="user-name">
      <b>Теплавина Евгения</b>
      <span class="pull-right"><span class="icons icon-phone"></span> 25-354</span>
      <div>инженер</div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Автор так и не дала мне понять, что `border` играет роль разделителя между `<a>`, а ты сообразил :)

Answer (score 4):

`last-child` в теге `<а>` это `<div class='username'>`, он же `first-child`

Чтобы убрать подчёривание у ссылок `a { text-decoration: none; }`

```css
.username b, .username span, .username div {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FF0000;
}

.username :last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='grouplist found-item'>
    <a href=''>
      <div class='username'>
        <b>Теплов Алексей</b>
        <span class='pullright'><span class='icons icon-phone'></span> 25-354</span>
        <div>руководитель группы</div>
      </div>
    </a>
</div>
```